# Is setContentIntent(PendingIntent) required in NotificationCompat.Builder?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Calling :

```
public static void triggerTestNotification(Context ctx, String tag, int id) {
    Notification not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Text")
        .setAutoCancel(true) // cancel on click
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(tag, id, not);
}
```

in `onCreate()` of my main activity yields :

```
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android/gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android id=0 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x10)
//...
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android id=0 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x10)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:133)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.C.triggerTestNotification(C.java:200)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
11-17 15:58:46.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1507):     ... 11 more
```

Notice the *[contentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentIntent) required*.

However the docs [could not be more clear](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification) :

> **Required notification contents**
>
> A Notification object must contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
> - A title, set by setContentTitle()
> - Detail text, set by setContentText()
>
> **Optional notification contents and settings**
>
> All other notification settings and contents are optional. To learn more about them, see the reference documentation for NotificationCompat.Builder.

This opinion is reflected in [various](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902307/281545) SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392090/281545) and results in SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008226/notificationcompat2-error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception) (and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682335/notificationcompat-builder-doesnt-work-android-2-2-1) one).

workaround :

```
final Intent emptyIntent = new Intent();
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, NOT_USED,
    emptyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//...
.setContentIntent(pi).build;
```

But is this really needed ? Is all this situation another *Android docs bug* ? Is it API dependent ?

NB my target SDK is 17 and running this on a 2.3.7 phone

Comment: Having a `Notification` with no `contentIntent` is a UX smell, IMHO. If your app is important enough to badger the user with a `Notification`, give the user something to do in response to that `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks (I use it for a battery low warning where the user has just to be reminded to turn the app on - dunno) - but isn't an IllegalArgumentException too much of a punishment for a smell ? Anyway I knew about this behavior - I just ask cause I believe that if it is indeed so an issue must be raised at google. It is plain unacceptable - except if I miss something.

Comment: "I use it for a battery low warning where the user has just to be reminded to turn the app on" -- then you should be using a `PendingIntent` that turns the app on (whatever that means).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use a caching service like waybackmachine and you look for [previous versions](http://web.archive.org/web/20110225195902/http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) of the Notifications guide, you will see that the guide does tell you that the `contentIntent` is required.

This is reflected in the Android source as well. `NotificationManagerService` handles the checking of Notifications before displaying them.

In [`Gingerbread`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java), as part of the `enqueueNotificationInternal()` method, it has this check:

```
if (notification.icon != 0) {
    if (notification.contentView == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("contentView required: pkg=" + pkg
                    + " id=" + id + " notification=" + notification);
    }
    if (notification.contentIntent == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("contentIntent required: pkg=" + pkg
                + " id=" + id + " notification=" + notification);
    }
}
```

On later Android versions, such as [`Ice Cream Sandwich`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr0/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java), that check is gone:

```
if (notification.icon != 0) {
    if (notification.contentView == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("contentView required: pkg=" + pkg
              + " id=" + id + " notification=" + notification);
    }
}
```

Thus, a `contentIntent` is *required* on Gingerbread and below.

Comment: this, sir, is what I call _an answer_ :)