# NotificationCompat in Android gingerbread doesn't work

Tags: android

I used to read [this topic about NotificationCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032249/is-setcontentintentpendingintent-required-in-notificationcompat-builder) and I know that the contentIntent is required on Gingerbread and below. However, I'm working in android Gingerbread and I don't want to add PendingIntent. What should I do to have the correct notification?
 
Thanks for your help

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentTitle("Basic notification");
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    try {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(8, notification);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

**Exception : contentIntent required: pkg=com.example.notificationtutorial id=8 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x10)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the contentIntent for your notification.

In your case You have to create a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) and setter PendingIntent in your notification.

```
notification.contentIntent = notificationIntent;
```

otherwise you will get the message, that the contentIntent of the notification is null, because it's not set.

The documentation is here:[Notification.html#contentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentIntent)

Example: [NotificationCompat Example](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/02/Android-notification-example.html)